# Power conversion to temperature formula

Tags: power, temperature

When an electrical shortcut occurs at a wire, the wire heats up to its melting point ([example](https://youtu.be/DJOX0c60wQE)). Is there a formula to calculate the temperature reached?

What I mean is, how to calculate the amount of power (I meant to say current) needed to reach the melting point of an electrically conductive material X that can be copper, aluminum, or an alloy? Is there a formula?

Comment: This is a thermal issue, not an electrical issue. You need to know the thermal properties of the wire.

Comment: The temperature reached is the melting point of the wire, which you can look up. Similarly you can look up the fusing current for a wire of given metal and gauge.

Comment: Thermal system characteristics can be modeled similarly to how DC electrical circuit characteristics are modeled, where thermal resistance and heat capacity are used in the model like the way electrical resistance and capacitance are used in DC circuit model. However there's not a direct relationship between electrical resistance and thermal resistance, you have to rely on the physical material properties for the correct values. The actual formula comes from the model the same way that a DC circuit formula comes from the circuit topology. So you find the formula by building the system model.

Comment: conservation of energy.  figure out how much leaves the wire as a function of temperature.  the rest goes into increasing the temp of the wire (mind that specific heat varies with temperature too)

Comment: What i need to know is let say at 5 volt 10 amps what gonna be temperature on a conductive material in celsius.

Comment: What conductive material? The type, dimensions etc are crucial. The first thing is to estimate the resistance. That gives a hint as to how much energy is going to be converted to heat.

Comment: Kartman that why i need a formula where i can replace all the Xs

Comment: Voltage is irrelevant here unless you plan on a flashover.

Comment: @winny at that time i didnt knew that information but now i know it depond on resistance and current, you mean arc by flashover?

Comment: That's fine. At 5 V, there will not be any flashovers. My point is that you can ignore the voltage here as it won't affect how hot the wire will become

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum current a conductor can carry before it starts to melt is called the “fusing current.” The first people typically credited with looking into this question for copper conductors are Sir William Henry Preece during the 1880s and I. M.  [Onderdonk](https://pcdandf.com/pcdesign/index.php/magazine/10179-pcb-design-1507).
The Onderdonk equation seems to be more specific and there for more accurate than the Preece equation.
Preece equation is a simple method, but actually it does not treat other characteristics such as fusing time and ambient temperature.

I = A*D^1.5

Where A is a constant depending on the metal and D is the diameter of the wire.

Preece coefficient (A)
[image: Table of Preece coefficients for different metals]
Image source: [Paper - Analysis of Dispersive Characteristics and Structures of Copper Wire Melted by Overcurrent](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/ieejpes/125/12/125_12_1327/_pdf/-char/en), from IEEJ Transactions on Power and Energy, 2005 Volume 125 Issue 12 1327-1331, https://doi.org/10.1541/ieejpes.125.1327

The advantage of the Onderdonk equation is that it allows more characteristics that suit my needs, especially the melting point of the conductive materials and the time.
And also the ambient temperature which represent the environment that can be room temperature ~25 C° or it can be less in a vacuum or kiln.
Also, I think (to be experimented) if the melting point temperature is replaced by a different temperature lets say 300 C° we can then achieve a power conversion to temperature.
But the Onderdonk equation doesn't include the resistivity of the material or its length.

[image: Onderdonk equation]
Image source: [WeldWell - Technique: Electrical Connections](http://www.weldwell.com.tw/%E7%81%AB%E6%B3%A5%E7%86%94%E6%8E%A5/cat-w1-16.pdf)

I think now days Onderdonk equation still used by printed circuit board (PCB) designer.

Answer (score 1):

"What i need to know is let say at 5 volt 10 amps what gonna be temperature on a conductive material in celsius (sic)"

It's not easy  in general. The eventual temperature it reaches depends on a couple obvious things - the power dissipated and the ambient temperature, and a bunch of other things- the geometry, the actual temperatures and intermediate materials such as air (heat transfer is via several different modes such as conduction, convection and radiation- sometimes you can ignore one or the other, but it changes depending on temperatures and temperature differences and geometries). Convection and radiation are very nonlinear, are temperature dependent and geometry comes into it- such as laminar flow and turbulence.

For simple things like insulated wires operating close to room temperature you can look up the temperature rise for typical simple situations (still air, some different numbers of them bundled etc) but the answers will be approximate and probably based on experiments someone did many decades ago.

If you have a more complex situation you have a few options

- make a bunch of simplifying assumptions and attempt an approximation
- build a mock-up and test it
- use a simulation program such as [Comsol](https://www.comsol.com/video/introduction-to-modeling-heat-transfer-in-comsol-multiphysics) to build a model (but you might still want to confirm it is correct).

A simulation can tell you temperatures that are hard to physically measure and it can also tell you what happens dynamically- how quickly the temperature changes. Often you can approximate the heat capacity of a solid with a constant, but the way heat spreads through a solid is not easily calculated in closed form.

In some special cases- especially where conduction dominates- you can easily use a SPICE program such as [LTspice](https://youtu.be/5CcDjbdaAM8) to simulate the dynamic characteristics. It's unnecessary to use a program to determine the final temperatures, a pen and paper will suffice.

Comment: "the answers will be approximate and probably based on experiments" so there is no formula?

Comment: @autodidact There is no simple formula. Of course various folks may have calculated simplified situations or curve-fit data to empirical methods.

Comment: I noted four points : 1- power dissipation (resistance of material and current) 2- ambient temperature (room temperature?) 3- geometry (shape and size of the material) 4- intermediate materiel (insulator for cable or isolater container). Two of those are given in cable section.

Comment: Power conversion to temperature.

Comment: What did you mean?

Comment: I think what i was looking for is fusing current [your opinion matter](https://pcdandf.com/pcdesign/index.php/magazine/10179-pcb-design-1507)

Comment: There are empirical tables of fusing current. You can refer to [such a table](http://pages.interlog.com/~speff/usefulinfo/fusing.htm). I put the linked one up on the net 25 years ago. Today there are others available.

Answer (score 1):

> When an electrical shortcut happens at a wire, the wire heat up to melting point

If the wire melting is the thing that stops the current flow, yes.

If the liquid metal can be kept in shape by a ceramic container, then it can get hotter.

Unlike the flame temperature of gases, which has a maximum temperature (oxygen + acetylene can reach a higher flame temperature than air + propane for instance), there is no maximum temperature associated with electrical heating. There are practical difficulties with keeping the components physically together, and being able to supply enough energy to make up for thermal losses, but these are not thermodynamic problems, only practical.

When a current is passed through a cable, fuse or component, we usually use one of two limiting models to work out what happens.

The fast heating *adiabatic* model assumes no heat is lost to the surroundings, and only goes to heat the component's thermal capacity.

The slow heating *thermal equilibrium* model assumes all the heat is lost to the surroundings, and the component is at constant temperature, in a state of balance where heat lost to ambient is equal to heat generated in the wire. The estimation of thermal resistance to ambient is very tricky, which is why regulations give tables of current versus wire size versus installation situation that have been found to not start too many house fires.

Obviously all real situations are a mix of this, but are usually predominantly one or the other.

A cable carrying a 'working' current can be considered to be in thermal equilibrium. Reduce heat loss (increase thermal resistance to ambient) by running it under a blanket, and it will get hotter.

A fuse breaking under an overload current can be considered to be adiabatic. It will heat until a time given by its I<sup>2</sup>t rating, a convenient number that sums up its resistance, thermal capacity and melting point, and gives you the time for the fuse to blow under strong overload conditions. Fuse manufacturers often provide 'time to blow' versus current graphs. The bends in the plots illustrate nicely the difference between adiabatic and equilibrium regions.

Comment: Have you watched the video?

Comment: @autodidact Not at 11 minutes. Let me know what time the bit you're interested appears at, and I've have a peep. It may provide context for your question, but it would only cause me to add stuff to my answer, not delete anything.

Comment: Very clear so we are talking ampacity, by knowing the overload capacity by the time (fusing current) plus insulation losses (most cable uses PVC continuous operation are usually 60 C°) we can say that by applying a known amount of current to a specific cable size for an X time the cable will melt.

Comment: @autodidact In the adiabatic case, where times are short, and heat loss to the environment is negligible, yes, we can say that a cable will melt after a certain time at a certain current, given by the fusing I2t. In the long time case, then the environment of the cable (in a conduit, other cables nearby, ambient temperature, airflow, thermal insulation) is critical, possibly altering the rated current by an order of magnitude, and failure will be by insulation softening, not the conductor melting.

Comment: So what i were after is the fusing current [Preece and Onderdonk](https://pcdandf.com/pcdesign/index.php/magazine/10179-pcb-design-1507)

Answer (score 1):

``Onderdonk's equation for fusing current'' relates time, temperature, and current in a wire. The following is a simplified derivation for Onderdonk's equation for fusing current which I originally posted here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/718543, but I've made some modifications.

Consider a solid wire with a current passing through it.

Let:
\$i\$ = current (A)
\$t\$ = time (s)
\$t_0\$ = reference time (s)
\$\Delta t  = t - t_0 \$ = time difference (s)
\$T\$ = average wire temperature (°C)
\$T_0\$ = reference temperature (°C)
\$L\$ = wire length (m)
\$A\$ = wire cross sectional area (m\$^2\$)
\$\rho\$ = mass density of the wire (kg /m\$^3\$)
\$c_P\$ = specific heat (J / Kg K)
\$R\$ = electrical resistance (Ω)
\$\alpha\$ = temperature coefficient of resistivity (1 / K)
\$\rho_0\$ = electrical resistivity at the reference temperature (Ω m)

Assume:

1. Current is applied to the conductor at time \$t_0\$.
2. Before application of current, the temperature of the conductor is \$T_0\$.
3. The outside of the wire is perfectly insulated (heat can’t escape).
4. The wire is very long.
5. The wire is very thin.
6. The resistivity of the wire is linear with respect to temperature.

As a current passes through the wire, the increase in thermal energy must equal the heat dissipated by Joule heating:

\$c_p \, \rho \,  A \,  L \, \left(T - T_0\right) = R \,  i^2 \, \Delta t\$

We are assuming there is no thermal conduction down the length of the wire due to assumption 5. Because of assumptions 3 and 4 we can neglect thermal conduction perpendicular to the wire. This means that \$T\$ represents an average wire temperature.

The electrical resistance is given by (assumption 6):
\$R=\frac{ \rho_0 \, \left(1 + \alpha \, \left(T - T_0\right) \right) \, L} {A}\$

Combining the equations, eliminating \$L\$, and rearranging:
\$ \frac{\left(T - T_0\right)} {\Delta t} = \frac{i^2 \, \rho_0} {c_p\, \rho \, A^2} \left(1 + \alpha \, \left(T - T_0\right) \right)\$

Turning the left hand side into a differential:
\$ \frac{d \, \left(T - T_0\right)} {d \, \Delta t} = \frac{i^2 \, \rho_0} {c_p\, \rho \, A^2} \left(1 + \alpha \, \left(T - T_0\right) \right)\$

Solving:

\$T - T_0 = C \, e^{\frac{i^2 \, \rho_0 \alpha \Delta t} {c_p\, \rho \, A^2}} -\frac{1} {\alpha}\$

where \$C\$ is an unknown which can be solved for by assumptions 1 and 2 (\$T - T_0 = 0\$ at \$\Delta t = 0\$). This yields \$C = \frac{1} {\alpha}\$

Solving for the change in time:

\$\Delta t = \frac{c_p\, \rho \, A^2} {i^2 \, \rho_0 \, \alpha}  \text{ln}\left( 1 + \alpha \left(T - T_0\right)\right) \$

For a given amount of time, You can use the previous equation to determine how much current is needed to melt a wire by replacing \$T\$ with the melt temperature.

Please note, for a real wire (with heat escaping, violating assumption #3) Onderdonk’s equation over predicts the temperature rise in a given amount of time. Also, the Onderdonk’s equation doesn't take skin effects into consideration, which means that it is not applicable when time is very small (like microseconds).

The following are two good references with derivations, assumptions, and some discussion of the shortcomings of the equation:

https://adam-research.de/pdfs/TRM_WhitePaper10_AdiabaticWire.pdf

https://web.archive.org/web/20190810140830/http://www.ultracad.com/articles/preece.pdf

I've used Onderdonk’s equation in the past when deciding what gage wires to use between a supply and load in the event the load short circuits, but the protection circuit on the supply has a finite delay time before it reacts.